# Save data in express-session

Tags: node.js, express, session

I would like save my token after login on express-session. My request is :

```
app.prepare().then(() => {
  express()
    .use(session({
        secret: 'this-is-a-secret-token',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
      }))
    .get(server.login_check, async (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.session.token);
      console.log('------------');

      if (!req.session.token) {
        try {
          const request = await loginThroughApi();

          if (request) {
            console.log(request);
            req.session.token = request.token;
            return request.token;
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('Error:', error);
        }
      } else {
        console.log(req.session.token);
      }
    })
```

`req.session.token` is always undefined, i don't really understand why ^^

Answer (score 0):

I am not realy sure how you initalized your up before the code you shared, but i think you should do `app.use(session(...))` and not `express.use(session(...))`. Again this depends on how you have set this variables. Maybe you can follow the initialization guide [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session).

Answer (score 0):

You need call like this

```
req.session.token = request.token;
req.session.save();
```