# express-session doesn't save

Tags: node.js, session, shopify, express-session

I am writing a simple server for a small app for Shopify. After getting the token for my app, I wanted to save it to session so I used `express-session`. However it didn't work.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52718364/save-data-in-express-session) solution in the code below.

The guys over github also have this issue:

https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/371

https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/633

Here is my **configuration**:

```
app.use(session({ 
    secret: 'new app',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {maxAge: 24*60*60*1000}
}))
```

This is the code for **getting token and save** it:

```
request.post(accessTokenRequestUrl, { json: accessTokenPayload })
        .then((accessTokenResponse) => {
            const accessToken = accessTokenResponse.access_token;
            const shopRequestUrl = 'https://' + shop + '/admin/themes.json';
            const shopRequestHeaders = {
                'X-Shopify-Access-Token': accessToken,
            };

            request.get(shopRequestUrl, {headers: shopRequestHeaders})
            .then((shopRes) => {
                let shopObj = JSON.parse(shopRes)
                let themeId = shopObj.themes[0].id;


                req.session.token = accessToken;
                req.session.save();
                console.log(req.session);

                res.json({
                    themeId: themeId,
                    token: accessToken
                })
            })

        })
```

My console.log after this. I says that I have the token in session object:

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-02-27T09:01:18.638Z,
     originalMaxAge: 86400000,
     httpOnly: true },
  token: '1354658af88b9417d3c268dd3c22eae4' }
```

However in another route:

```
app.get('/shopify/callback/images', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session);
    res.send(req.session.token);
})
```

I got this

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-02-27T09:03:56.280Z,
     originalMaxAge: 86400000,
     httpOnly: true } }
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

First, a Promise should always return a Promise if there is any async job in it.

```
return request.get(shopRequestUrl, {headers: shopRequestHeaders})
```

Plus, it's a best practice to always add a `.catch()` in a Promises chain.

But the real issue here is that [req.session.save()](https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionsavecallback) is asynchronous and takes a callback function.

```
req.session.token = accessToken;
req.session.save(() => {
  console.log(req.session);

  return res.json({
    themeId : themeId,
    token   : accessToken,
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes I fixed it according to your ideas. I removed `catch()` for production but it might not be a good idea. I returned my Promise and add `req.session.save((err) => {
                        if (!err) {
                            console.log('token is saved!')
                        }
                    });` but it didn't change the result. Btw it sounds dump but why we need a callback for `req.session.save()`? Is it for avoiding error?

Comment: The session is saved automatically at the end of a request. If you want it accessible immediately, you must call `save()`. But if you call `console.log(req.session)` before the session is saved, you get nothing.

Comment: Thank you I get it now! I think I will switch to another database to store token and themeId since session will wipe out data when the server restarts.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it's because the cookies were not sent in the first place.

I was using `axios` and I had to set the option `{ withCredentials: true }` when making requests.

I hope it helps.